# How to draw minor rivers in Matplotlib basemap?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I am plotting a very high resolution (100m resolution) map using Matplotlib Basemap. Everything looks good, except that I can't seem to find a way to make basemap draw a minor river that runs through the simulated area.
Does anyone know how to do this?!

```
m = Basemap(resolution='h', projection='stereo',\
        width=85000, height=61000,\
        lat_ts=51.4255, lat_0=51.4255, lon_0=-106.225)
m.drawrivers()
```

Comment: I suspect you need the shape files for those rivers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change resolution on full (resolution='f')